# Biblatex: how to remove 'In:' (Teoksessa:') from bibliography (for languages other than English)?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is there a way to remove *In:* and its equivalents from all the entries in the bibliography, no matter the language of the entry? I tried `\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}`, but that doesn't have an effect on the Finnish entry (*Teoksessa:* remains):

**Täht, Põhja 2020**. Taevas. Teoksessa: - Linnunrata. Toim. Kosmo Naut.

(what I want instead is: **Täht, Põhja 2020**. Taevas. - Linnunrata. Toim. Kosmo Naut.)

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@inbook{Taht2020,
langid = {finnish},
title = {Taevas},
booktitle = {Linnunrata},
author = {Põhja Täht},
editor = {Kosmo Naut},
year = {2020},
}

@inbook{Taht2019,
langid = {english},
title = {Taevas},
booktitle = {Linnunrata},
author = {Põhja Täht},
editor = {Kosmo Naut},
year = {2019},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[finnish, english, estonian]{babel}

\usepackage[bibencoding=auto, backend=biber, autolang = other, style=authoryear, sorting=debug, dashed=false, citestyle=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{xpatch, filecontents}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
    \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {}
        {\textbf{\printnames{shortauthor}%
         \addspace{=}\space}}}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1\addperiod{\space}}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{booktitle}{--{\space}#1\addperiod}

\begin{document}

Citing different works \parencite{Taht2019, Taht2020}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the Estonian and Finnish language module of `biblatex` redefine the bibmacro `in:` in the bibliography language extras. If you want to redefine this macro yourself, you need to do that in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{<language>}`.

I suggest you redefine `in:` in such a way that you no longer need to include punctuation commands in the field formats for `title` and `booktitle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[finnish, english, estonian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2,
  dashed=false,
  autolang=other
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \printtext[parens]%
}{%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printtext%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
    {}
    {\textbf{\printnames{shortauthor}%
     \addspace{=}\space}}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{estonian}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{in:}{\printunit{\addperiod\addspace--\space}}}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{finnish}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{in:}{\printunit{\addperiod\addspace--\space}}}


\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\egroup}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{bbx:editor}{\egroup}{}{}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{Taht2020,
  langid    = {finnish},
  title     = {Taevas},
  booktitle = {Linnunrata},
  author    = {Põhja Täht},
  editor    = {Kosmo Naut},
  year      = {2020},
}
@inbook{Taht2019,
  langid    = {english},
  title     = {Taevas},
  booktitle = {Linnunrata},
  author    = {Põhja Täht},
  editor    = {Kosmo Naut},
  year      = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Citing different works \autocite{Taht2019, Taht2020}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Täht, Põhja 2019. Taevas. In: Linnunrata. Ed. by Kosmo Naut.//Täht, Põhja 2020. Taevas. – Linnunrata. Toim. Kosmo Naut.]

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Please see moewe's comment below on why not to do this.**

Putting the following in your preamble should work:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{finnish}{
  in = {}
}
```

Comment: Please don't do that! Redefining strings to be empty in order to suppress them is in general quite bad style. If you don't want a string in the output, tell the bibmacro or field format that uses it not to do so.

Comment: Noted; thanks for the heads-up!